# Mail not received in TYPO3 default form

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have used default TYPO3 form into my application and configure email id in Recipient Email.

The problem is that form is not working with all email ids. what is the problem with this and how to check?

Comment: We don't know the problem, since there is nothing to look at...
Post some code, and tell us what you want it to do, what it is doing now, and what the problem is.

Comment: I create one contact form with TYPO3 default form but recipient not getting mail every time. That is TYPO3 default form.

Comment: Can you test in install tool from TYPO3, if email sending is working?

Comment: @jokumer Yes, it is working in install tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possiblities why the mail don't reached the receiver.

**First**: It can be detected as spam because your Server is not allowed to send mails from the domain setted at `[MAIL][defaultMailFromAddress]` in the install tool or your sender settings in the form settings. Here it can be helped to set an valid [SPF record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) in the nameserver of your domain.

**Second**: The junk or spam filter on the client side push the mail into the junk or spam folder because some keywords in your mail or too little content.

**Third**: Your server has an restriction of outgoing mails over the php `mail` command.

Maybe you can try to set `[MAIL][transport]` in your install tool to `smtp` and set `[MAIL][transport_smtp_server]`, `[MAIL][transport_smtp_username]` and `[MAIL][transport_smtp_password]` to the corresponding settings.